# Simulating Internal error in Paypal express sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal-sandbox

I have some special actions defined for the case when requesting to Paypal returns Internal errors(10001). I want to regenerate the condition so that I can test my code. I also want to test the other failure cases.

How to run negative tests for Paypal express sandbox?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to stub out these error requests (if not all of them). For a fancier front-end, you can use an abstraction like [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to generate the stub requests.

You can do something like,

```
stub_request(:any, "www.example.com").to_return(:status => [500, "Internal Server Error"])
```

But be sure to get he correct status code and body content for PayPal errors.